# "initializer element is not constant" while creating an Init function

Tags: c, initialization

Right now I am trying to implement an Init function for Pre-configured staff. However as in the following code when I try to implement certain function I receive an error `initializer element is not constant`. I have read many questions with same error however I couldn't relate one to my case.

The code is as follows:

```
#define CURR_CONFIG_X        4
#define CURR_CONFIG_Y        4
#define CURR_CONFIG_Z        4

typedef struct {
    bool *tblX;
    bool *tblY;
    bool *tblZ;
} indicesInUse_t;

typedef struct {
    tblPreCfgs_t *tblPreCfgs;
    indicesInUse_t *tblEntryIndicesInUse;
} tblMgmt_t;

indicesInUse_t cfgIndicesInUse(indicesInUse_t *currIndicesInUse); //error takes place in this line

static indicesInUse_t currTblIndicesInUse = cfgIndicesInUse(&currTblIndicesInUse);

static tblMgmt_t flowTbleMgmt = {
    .tblEntryIndicesInUse = &currTblEntryIndicesInUse,
};

indicesInUse_t cfgIndicesInUse(indicesInUse_t *currIndicesInUse) {
    for (uint16_t index = 0; index < CURR_CONFIG_X; index++) {
        currIndicesInUse->tblX[index] = true;
    }

    for (uint16_t index = 0; index < CURR_CONFIG_Y; index++) {
        currIndicesInUse->tblYindex] = true;
    }

    for (uint16_t index = 0; index < CURR_CONFIG_Z; index++) {
        currIndicesInUse->tblZ[index] = true;
    }

    return *currIndicesInUse;
}
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? Please [edit] your question to include a comment on the exact line where the error is reported.

Comment: You cannot initialize a global variable with anything else than a constant. `int foo = 2;` is OK, `int foo = somefunction(bar);` is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an instance of where you will get the error:

```
static indicesInUse_t currTblIndicesInUse = cfgIndicesInUse(&currTblIndicesInUse);
```

Here `currTblIndicesInUse` is a `static` variable, so its initializer must be a constant expression.  That means it cannot contain dynamically executed code, such as a function call.

There are two ways this can be solved.  One is to change the initializer so that it's a constant expression.  The other is to remove the initializer, and instead initialize the variable with an assignment statement (inside a function).  You would then call that function to initialize it.

For example, the simplest constant initializer would be something like:

```
static indicesInUse_t currTblIndicesInUse = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

The `NULL` values could also be the addresses of static `bool` variables, or `bool` arrays.

To initialize it dynamically, you'd simply call a function, passing it the address of the `struct`.  The function would then simply set the fields of the structure, e.g.

```
    s_ptr->tblX = ptr_x;
    s_ptr->tblY = ptr_y;
    s_ptr->tblZ = ptr_z;
```

You would need to fill in the specifics yourself, depending on what you want to achieve.

Note that in the original posted code, even if the dynamic initializer were allowed, it still wouldn't work because space is never allocated
for the pointer variables.  It might be helpful to read a tutorial on how pointers work.

Comment: can you explain more with an example, how to implement both options?

Comment: Ok, I added more details, but you should probably try to understand pointers a little better before worrying too much about initializers.  There are additional problems in the code that will require fixing (such as allocating space for your arrays).